# Auto List Member não funciona com javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, editor-de-texto

Eu uso Visual Studio 2015, estou tendo problema de não exibir auto list member no javascript.

> *Já fui na **configuração** > **Editor de texto** > **JavaScript** > **Geral**.
>
> *Já reparei Visual Studio 2015 no **painel de controle** e nada resolveu.
>
> *Já fui **TOOLS** > **Import and Export Settings** > **Reset all Settings**

**OBS**: Reinstalei Visual Studio, Auto List Member voltou a funcionar, no dia seguinte ela sumiu.

Já tenho as opções marcadas `Auto list members` e `Parameter information`, porem ela não funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um tempo atrás funcionava, mais agora não aparace mais.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu digito qualquer letrar, ela não acontece nada. O que pode ser esse problema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema. O problema estava relacionado com NuGet.

Vai no menu **PROJECT** > **Manage NuGet Packages**, Vai desinstalando cada uma para ver se realmente resolve o problema. Então descobri o problema quem estava impedindo a mostrar auto list member. O problema era "JQuery.UI.Combined".